# Rails - duplicate form and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have simply duplicated a file (edit.html.erb) and named it (weight.html.erb) and have simply changed a few of the header tags.

To link to the original file I used (this works):

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(@user) %>
```

So, I imagined to link to the new file I should use:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit weight', weight_user_path(@user) %>
```

This throws an undefined method `user_path' error.

Assuming this has to do with my routes.rb file I added

```
resources :weight
```

But I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

`resources` is a helper for the whole CRUD routes.

You would want to do

```
resources :users do
  get :weight
end
```

then run `rake routes` to see it added.